# Is it possible to access a getter function as the function rather than the return value

Tags: javascript

For example

```js
const obj = {
  get test() {
    return 'something'
  }
}
```

Is there a way to return `obj.test` as the function itself as opposed to `'something'`, as there is currently a use case where I don't want the function to execute immediately. Or is the only method to make it not a getter function

Comment: You could always create a normal method and getter, eg `const ob = { getTest() { return "something" }, get test() { return this.getTest() } }`

Comment: Use an anonymous function: `function() { return obj.test; }` when you don't want it to execute immediately.

Comment: If you want deferred execution, you could just wrap it: `() => obj.test` and use that in any context where you need a function that evaluates later.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the function in a separated variable and define the getter with the [__defineGetter__ method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__):

```js
const obj = {}

var obj_getter = function(){
    return 'something'
};

obj.__defineGetter__('test', obj_getter);

console.log(typeof obj_getter);
console.log(obj.test);
```

And the result is

```js
"function"
"something"
```